# How to avoid while-loop code duplication?

Tags: while-loop, duplicates

```
string s = Console.ReadLine();
while(s != null)
{
    // do something 
    //   ....
    s = Console.ReadLine(); 
}
```

The code above is to get the input, verify it, process it and then input again, but obviously, `s = Console.ReadLine();` is code duplication.

What tricks are there to avoid the duplication?

Comment: that is the typical pattern of `while` statement unless you do a while(true)

Comment: Which language is this? Most support a [`do-while` loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_while_loop) that is useful for situations like this.

Answer (score 2):

depending on language, you can often do something like this:

```
while (s = Console.ReadLine())
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()` doesn't return a bool

Comment: This is pretty clearly described as a language agnostic answer. If Java is indeed the target language, then this is pretty easily modified by using `while (null != (s = Console.ReadLine())`.

Answer (score 2):

In Python (where there is no `do-while` loop to guaranteed at least one iteration), the trick is to use an infinite loop with an explicit break.

```
while( true )  // Or whatever evaluates to true unconditionally
{
    s = Console.ReadLine();
    if (s == null) {
        break;
    }
    // do something
}
```